# Run local python script and data, from remote server

Tags: linux, terminal, python, remote

I want to run a local python script with local input folder containing data, output folder for saving output files, and a subject id using a remote server.

I tried different codes for example,

1. ssh host@IP python -u - < script.py -s subj_id -i input_folder -o output_folder_name
2. ssh host@IP python -u - --opt s subj_id -i input -o output_dir < script.py
3. ssh host@IP "python script.py -s subj_id -i input -o output_dir"
4. ssh host@IP 'cd remote_dir && python -u - myfifo' < script.py

but I get different **errors** such as:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 45, in 
File "", line 42, in main
File "", line 26, in make_dirs

bash: -o: No such file or directory

bash: line 0: cd: too many arguments

Unknown option: -o

usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.

**meanwhile, I have some questions:**

1. Should I be on the local script directory when running the terminal bash?
2. Should I use a complete directory for local script when I define it? such as, /media/machine/.../folder/script.py
3. Should I use a complete directory for each local argument (input, output, subj)?
   such as, /media/machine/.../data/input_folder
4. Can I get output files back on my local PC from a local script running with ssh on server?
5. Could you please guide me on how to remotely run a local script with local input and local output?

Comment: Just because you are using `ssh` doesn't mean the remote server can magically access local files. So **how** do you want to manage that? Remote filesystem? Copying all files to remote server, then back? Something else? Decide how you want to solve that, then you can think about details.

Comment: I mean by using “Remote filesystem”. I want to have the input data and script on my local PC, then run it on remote server, and get the results back on a folder on my local PC.

Comment: Then systematically debug it: First run the python command directly on the remote server, with the remote filesystem mounted. Once that works without errors, try calling it via `ssh`.

Comment: Your remote server probably doesn't have access to files on your local PC.  So: 1. copy the local file(s) to the server (e.g. with `scp`).  2. copy the script too if it isn't already on the server (and install any dependencies it might need).  3. run the script.  4. copy the output file(s) back to the local machine.   BTW, **if** you're copying text files between windows and unix machines, be aware of the difference in line-endings - Windows uses CR+LF, unix uses LF only. You'd need to convert with `fromdos` or similar.

Comment: @dirkt , I moved all the data and scripts to the server using scp. I have run the scripts with no error. Now, I want to try having all my data and scripts on my “local PC” and get run on the “server” without moving neither my data nor the scripts to the server, how can I do that? In addition, I didn’t got how to mount remote filesystems!!

Comment: Well, you said you wanted to do a remote filesystem. Decide on which filesystem you want (nfs, samba, sshfs, there's probably more...), install client and server, see how it goes. If you actually **don't** already have a remote filesystem working, moving data and script first is also perfectly fine. You can also use `rsync` via `ssh`, or even `parallel` to automate the setup (though `parallel` has a different main use-case).